# Taking the difference between mean and median and comparing this difference between features of different scales

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, median

Imagine I wanted to compare the skew between many different columns of a dataset. And imagine those columns were in different units and magnitudes, such as comparing a temperature scale to height.

Obviously these are not directly comparable since their scales are so different. This is why we normalize or standardize the data.

But what if I wanted to compare the “deltas” between features, where the delta is the difference between the mean and median for the feature.

Would these be comparable despite the different scales/units of the various features? Wouldn’t comparing deltas be a kind of normalization?

Comment: If you first standardize the variables - then the answer is yes. Z-standardization changes nothing in the distribution except that it sets the mean to zero and sd to 1. So then the (standardized) delta is just the standardized median.

Comment: This is equivalent to first compute the mean-median delta and then to divide it by the variable's sd.

Comment: Actually the median would be rescaled too under standardization, so standardizing first should work as you say. Take the delta as the difference between the rescaled mean (0) and the rescaled median. If a particular feature’s rescaled median is more extreme from 0 than another feature’s, the first feature should be considered as more deviant from its average value.